# C programming on linux: which distro and tools to use

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system

I normally use notepad++ with MinGW for compiling, for writing in C. But the debugger sometimes just don't work properly in windows, just like the compiler. So I sometimes use a linux-system, made by the Harvard University, but it is specified for a special study, and I was wondering what the best linux alternative is for programming in C. Which apps can I use the best for programming in linux, etc? I know it's a matter of taste, but I'm just looking for some good advice, which I can't really find with google, or at least, not really trustable advice :)

Comment: Just use whatever distribution you're comfortable with.

Comment: gcc is a great compiler embedded within C, nothing to install

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar, but i'm totally not familiar with the linux distros, what can you reccomend?

Comment: @GenieKort : Googling for "best linux distro" will let you make up your own mind. :)

Comment: Ubuntu's a fairly easy-to-use distro, and the basic C development tools (`gcc` compiler, `gdb` debugger, and all the necessary headers and libraries) should be preinstalled.  Use whatever editor you're comfortable with, as long as it saves files in plain text.  I've never warmed to full IDE for C development, so I can't make any recommendations there.  I do almost all my work in terminal sessions anyway, so it's all command-line for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu + emacs or vi (editor) + gcc (compiler) + gdb (debugger)

But since you are asking, you might be more interested in a full IDE. In that case you could give Netbeans or Eclipse a try.

Answer (score 0):

The best text editor to program in C on linux I think is Gedit.Try it,it's very powerful.

Comment: But which version of linux should i use? I know Gedit indeed, and i also think it's very good, but what about debuggers? Just gdb?